# PHP GD text borders showing up incorrectly with transparency

Tags: php, gd, transparent

I have seen other questions about this and I've tried using Alpha and imagetruecolortopalette to fix it but no dice. What I'm trying to do is make a page like text.php?test=somethinghere and it produces an image like this:

http://davzy.com/screenshots/Sample_20String-20110809-101622.png

I want the background to be transparent, but as you can see there's still some red there:

```
<?php
// The text to draw width
$text = $_GET['t'];
$font = 'fontname.ttf';

$width = imagettfbbox(7, 0, $font, $text);

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width[2] - $width[0] + 2, 11);
imagetruecolortopalette($im,false, 2);
imageSaveAlpha($im,true);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 108, 108, 108);
$red = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($im, 255, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

//draw borders
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 0, 8, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 2, 8, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 1, 7, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 1, 9, $grey, $font, $text);

//draw font
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 0, 7, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 2, 7, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 0, 9, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 2, 9, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 7, 0, 1, 8, $white, $font, $text);

//show
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Are you able to fix that?)) 8 years ago)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should change the 255 value of the $red ImageColorAllocateAlpha to 0:

```
$red = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
```

Comment: Now it's doing the same thing only with black

Comment: The black font outline is desirable, just not the little extra black at the beginning of the words right? Try making the ImageColorAllocateAlpha RGB white then: $red = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);

Comment: Now it's doing the exact same thing only with white